# Stop HTML iFrame function from running on page load

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, stripe-payments, velo

I have an HTML iFrame inside which there is a function which I do not want to run until the site sends a message using window.postMessage() to the iFrame.

My iFrame Code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script>
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
    window.onmessage = (event) => {
        if (event.data) {
        let jackpotId = event.data.id;
        myFunction(jackpotId);        
    }}

    function myFunction(jackpotId) { //this function runs on page load
    stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: jackpotId
        }).then(function (result) {

        });
    }
</script>
```

I want the above myFunction() to run only when the page runs this code:

```
let obj = {
    id: response.id
  };
$w("#html2").postMessage(obj);
```

Currently the iFrame function runs on page load and gives error in the console due to the missing session ID.

Comment: You do not show anything there that would cause the function to run on load. Are you sending other messages that do not contain an id? And have you verified that `obj.id` actually contains a value when `postMessage` is called?

Comment: No I'm not sending any other messages. Yes `obj.id` does contain a value because I get Stripe's Checkout Session ID and then post it to the HTML to redirect to Stripe's Checkout Page. I do not have anything else invoking the function, what you see above is all the code I have in the iFrame.

Comment: If you're not sending any other messages and the function is not being invoked anywhere else, then it is literally impossible for that function to be running except directly due to `postMessage(obj)`, which means `obj` has to be empty or else it contains an invalid session ID.